# Javascript Anonymous function vs no function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-function

Can someone please explain the difference between

1.`onChange= () => console.log("Changed")`

2.`onChange= console.log("Changed")`

I don't see the difference myself, so what is the point in using option 1?

I am using React here.

Comment: You're likely in the context of some framework that you've neglected to tell us about. Angular? React? Vue?

Comment: That's not JavaScript, maybe it's React or something?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it will be a little clearer if you removed the `{}`

`onChange = console.log('Changed');`

You're setting `onChange` to the return value of `console.log()`.

`onChange = () => console.log('Changed');`

You're setting `onChange` to a function that will be called when there's a change.